# Error de OBDC driver conexion de laravel con SQLServer

Tags: php, laravel, sql-server, laravel-5

> Cuando quiero hacer mi primer consulta que es un select obtengo este error y aun no he encontrado la solucion.

SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: No se puede establecer una conexión ya que el equipo de destino denegó expresamente dicha conexión. (SQL: select * from [alumnos])

> La consulta

```php
public function index()
    {
        return view('alumnos.index', ['alumnos', Alumnos::All()]);
    }
```

> La conexion la he hecho de esta forma

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=1433
DB_DATABASE=DBCDSRegAcademico
DB_USERNAME=sa
DB_PASSWORD='12345'
```

> Los drivers de php para sql server ya los he instalado e incluso he hecho conexiones sin utilizar laravel, y todo ha ido bien, pero ahora que estoy utilizando laravel, tengo ese error.

- El obdc esta instalado
- Ya verifique las credenciales.
- El puerto 1433 es enable.

Comment: que sistema operativo usas?

Comment: estoy utilzando windows

Comment: verifica que tengas habilitada las extenciones `php_sqlsrv_71_ts_x64.dll` y `​php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_ts_x64.dll`

Comment: si ya las hablite, pero las x86 ya que estoy utilizando XAMPP de 32

Comment: yv reiniciaste el servidor?

Comment: ```extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86.dll```
```extension=php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86.dll```

Comment: Si ya lo reinicie

Comment: El error retornado proviene de la base de datos, por lo que la conexión estará establecida correctamente. El problema tiene pinta de ser debido a que el usuario "sa" no tenga permiso para acceder a la BDD indicada "DBCDSRegAcademico" o bien que las credenciales no sean correctas. *Veo que la contraseña la has puesto con comillas, ¿podría ser eso? Un saludo.